# Display the list of files created yesterday in Unix

Tags: unix

How to display the list of files created yesterday in Unix. I am new to Unix and I tried the below script but couldn't get the result.

```
tdate=$( date +"%m/%d/%Y" )
ydate=$( date -d" -1 day" +"%m/%d/%Y" ) # Yesterday
stat -c "%y|%n" * | grep "ydate"
```

When I wrote

```
stat -c "%y|%n" * | grep "$date" ;
```

it gave me the files created today but when I wrote

```
stat -c "%y|%n" * | grep "tdate";
```

it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
find . -mtime -1
```

NOTA: You will only be able to acces the last modification time, which is different from the creation time.

Regarding your issue, `"tdate"` is a string, but `$tdate` would be the expanded string. So you can try with `grep "$tdate"` instead.

Comment: There exists `atime`, `ctime` as search options

Comment: I wrote grep "$tdate". It too didn't work. 
Actually, I need to run this script everyday dynamically in order to have the yesterday's file names  which I further need to store in an array.